# Wordpress Multisite - user registration stuck in wp-login loop

Tags: wordpress

I'm having trouble registering users on a Wordpress multisite. I can't seem to access the register screen, either from the main site, or from a sub-site. Clicking 'Register' just sends the user back to the Login screen.

The site is currently set up with two domains (a .org and a .org.uk), using the Domain Mapping plugin. The following options are set within the Domain Mapping plugin:

- Remote Login
- Permanent redirect (better for your blogger's pagerank)
- User domain mapping page
- Redirect administration pages to site's original domain (remote login disabled if this redirect is disabled)

Each sub-site is set to allow user registrations, and the network settings allow the follow option: 'User accounts may be registered.'

Interestingly, the site also runs Woocommerce, and users can register accounts from within this plugin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
David